# Minecraft loot table 1.14.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am in need to the answers to the following questions about loot tables in 1.14.4.

---

- What is the command to spawn in your custom loot table chest
- Wheres the directory to put the custom loot table in the .minecraft folder
- A working loot table generator for the latest version of Minecraft

---

p.s If I have got the wrong tags or theres another question on going that can 
    help. I am truly sorry

Answer (score 2):

1. `/give @p chest{BlockEntityTag:{LootTable:"custom_namespace:loot_table.json"}}` or `/setblock ~ ~ ~ chest{LootTable:"custom_namespace:loot_table.json"}`
2. `.minecraft/saves/nameOfWorld/datapacks/datapack_name/data/custom_namespace/loot_tables`
3. [Loot Table Generator for Minecraft](https://misode.github.io/loot-table)

You need to create a custom namespace for your loot table (the above assumes its `custom_namespace`) and also create a [pack.mcmeta](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_data_pack) file in the "datapack_name" folder. The command is for a loot table called `loot_table.json`. To specify a loot table in a folder, use `custom_namespace:folder/loot_table.json`.

More information: [Loot table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table)

Comment: Hi, I have tried that even keeping everything the same from your example but am still getting an empty chest and i don't know why I have my .json file in the loot_tables folder after the ".minecraft/saves/nameOfWorld/datapacks/data/customNamespace/loot_tables"  but it still happens.

Comment: @MatthewSmith Is the loot table's path `...customNamespace/loot_tables/loot_table.json` or `...customNamespace/loot_tables/loot_tables/loot_table.json`? From your comment, it seems like you've put the json file in another loot_tables folder inside the existing one.

Comment: Note that if you are in survival the chest you place down won't have any items in it. It only works if you are in creative and place it down, or if you use the setblock command instead.

Comment: Also, @cherryblossom, it seems like you skipped a portion of the directory and used improper casing. Did you actually test this yourself? You actually need to create a folder in between "datapacks" and "data" designating the name of the datapack, and it needs to have both the "data" folder in it as well as a "pack.mcmeta" file.

Comment: @ZachK I actually don't own Java Editon, so I couldn't test it. Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: So I have my folders and it goes `.minecraft/saves/MYMAP/datapacks/demo/data/custom_namespace/loot_tables` I have my loot_tablew.json inside the loot_tables folder and the pack.mcmeta in demo is this correct? @ZachK @cherryblossom

Comment: @MatthewSmith Yes, that is correct. Note you also need a pack.mcmeta file inside your "demo" folder. Type `/reload` and `/datapack list` in your world when you are done with your datapack. You should see "[demo]" show up in chat. Finally, you can check if the loot table has loaded correctly by using the `/loot` command.